# Creating mask over entire div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a mask over an image inside a div, but the mask does not cover the entire area of the div (leaves whitespace in the middle). Been trying to fix it but can't find a solution.

This is my progress - http://jsfiddle.net/E2aWr/164/

```css
.image-container {
    width: 254px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
    cursor: default;
}
.image-container .mask, .image-container .content {
    width: 250px;
    height: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.image-container img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.image-container a.info {
    background:url('link.png') center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:0;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
.effect .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow:visible;
    border:100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.effect a.info {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    /* Center the link */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}
.effect:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
    border:100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.effect:hover a.info {
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="image-container effect">
   <img src="http://www.istudy.net.my/images/shop/manufacturer/resized/bc_220x280.jpg.png" />
   <div class="mask"> 
      <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have border not background, Remove border from `mask` and add background

```
.effect:hover .mask {
   opacity: 1;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.effect .mask {
   opacity: 0;
   overflow:visible;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 2):

I remove the border style in this selector `.effect .mask` and changed the border style to background style.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 254px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}
.image-container .mask,
.image-container .content {
  width: 250px;
  height: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image-container img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.image-container a.info {
  background: url('link.png') center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.effect .mask {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.effect a.info {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  /* Center the link */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}
.effect:hover .mask {
  opacity: 1;
}
.effect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.effect .mask {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.effect:hover .mask {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container effect">
  <img src="http://www.istudy.net.my/images/shop/manufacturer/resized/bc_220x280.jpg.png" />
  <div class="mask"> <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.